# Including manually created color palette to package without direct referring to it

Tags: r, package, color-palette

I have a manually created color palette which my package is using. I have included my `.rds` color palette file into my package folder and I refer to it within my functions by `load(paste0(getwd(),'/my_palette.rds'))`. However I find it very unpractical for example if I want to share my package, and someone what to change his working directory - then the reference won't work. I'm looking for a solution which would build this color palette within R automatically while installing package so that I don't need to have exact file in package folder to which I have to refer. Is this possible ?

**EDIT**

I created data/ folder in my package folder using commands below :

```
x<-load(paste0(getwd(),'/my_palette.rds'))
usethis::usedata(x)
```

Then I clicked on this `.rda` in data/ folder to load this into my working directory. However I don't know how should I refer to it. `load('x')` doesn't work.

**EDIT vol 2**

I will describe full algorithm of adding `my_palette.rds` to my package which I'm applying :

1. Create manual color palette
2. Refer to it by command `x<-load(dir/my_palette.rds)`
3. Then I'm using command `usethis::use_data(x)` (then data/ folder is created with .rda file within it)
4. After that I'm using `ggplot2` function with `scale_fill_manual(my_package::x)`. The warning I get is : `Error: Unknown colour name: my_palette`

**EDIT vol 3**

I want to describe process of creating color palette so that we can see where is the basis of the error. So the main difference between what you did and what I did is that you created colour palette as a vector of color to future reference.
(This is very important, your colour palette is stored in a vector type). what I did is to create functions which create a colour palette and after that I saved it into `.rds` file. And I believe that it might be the main difference that my colour palette is stored within file. Do you think that it's significant difference ? Or it can be omitted somehow ?

Comment: I think you should [add data to your package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391195/include-data-examples-in-developing-r-packages) or create a function that returns the palette.

Comment: Let's assume that I have my function which creates manually color palette in R folder. How can I refer to that palette ?

Comment: have you tried `name_of_your_package::name_of_your_data`?

Comment: I get the error following when trying to use it : Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 2 needed but only 1 provided.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I need more details to help you.

Comment: I will update my question shortly

Comment: I added brief description what I'm doing to add this palette

Answer (score 0):

The process for saving data within R packages is well described here: https://r-pkgs.org/data.html

You might prefer to use the Internal data approach, unless you want other users of your package to have access to the color palette.

Through the `usethis::use_data()`, you add an object in your Global environment to the data folder, or into `R/sysdata.rda` if you set `internal = TRUE`. When the package is loaded (e.g. `devtools::load_all()`) these data objects are loaded into the package environment.

The error you mention - `Error: Unknown colour name: my_palette` - suggests a problem in the way you've generated your color palette. It would be helpful to provide the code that generates your color palette to check this.

An example:

```
# define color palette
color_palette <- c("#c6d4e1", "#2f2016", "#fcfaea", "#456789")

# save to internal package data - saves data in R/sysdata.rda
usethis::use_data(color_palette, internal = TRUE)

# load package
devtools::load_all()

# refer to color palette
mypackage::color_palette[1]     # "#c6d4e"
```

Comment: Yes, I did completely the same as you did and I get same error so I believe you are right that the problem is in generating color palette. Please look at my answer to see how my color palette is generated.

Comment: @John - the fact that my color palette above is a vector isn't so important - the color palette simply needs to be an object (e.g. vector, list, data frame) that can be passed to `usethis::use_data()`. To better understand the error, can you show the structure of `my_package::x` from your original question, or the code you've used to generate my_palette.rds?